# Python `vis` module err . Python Solar System

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, python-module, python-visual

Hi I am trying to get the following github repo : https://github.com/lukekulik/solar-system
to work on my laptop and have installed all the modules required but for some reason when i try and run i get error cannot import module `vis` in `from vis import ...`.

It is in every file and i a using python 3.6.

The code for one file is below:

```
from vis import scene, label, vector, norm, cross
```

Error is here when trying to import vis and below when trying to import wx

```
#from pygame.mixer import music
from parameters import planets, n, am
from wx import Exit

lbl = label(text="    Simulation is paused. \n Press any key to continue.", 
visible=False, box=False)

# key_check function translates user keyboard into commands for the program:


def key_check(ship_mode, s, v, a, dt, sw_lbl, lbl_off, predraw, earthpos, t, 
ship):
if scene.kb.keys:  # check if there are any keys pressed in the queue

    key = scene.kb.getkey()  # retrieve the pressed key

    # change simulation speed: (steps are small on purpose; user has to 
press and hold for smooth transition)
    if key == 'q' and 1 <= dt < 125:
        dt += 2
    elif key == 'q' and dt <= 0.95:
        dt += 0.05
    elif key == 'a' and dt > 1:
        dt -= 2
    elif key == 'a' and 0.2 < dt <= 1:
        dt -= 0.05

    elif key == 'esc':
        Exit()  # exit the program

    elif key == 'p':
        lbl.visible = True  # show pause label
        lbl.pos = scene.center  # center the label on the screen
        scene.kb.getkey()  # wait for key input
        lbl.visible = False  # hide pause label

    elif key == 'x':
        if scene.stereo == 'nostereo':
            scene.stereo = 'redcyan'  # turn on 3D rendering mode (red-cyan)
        elif scene.stereo == 'redcyan':
            scene.stereo = 'crosseyed'  # turn on 3D rendering mode (cross-eyed)
        else:
            scene.stereo = 'nostereo'  # turn off 3D rendering mode

    elif key == 'l':
        sw_lbl = not sw_lbl  # planet/spaceship label switch
        lbl_off = not lbl_off

    elif key == 's':
        #if ship_mode:
 #  music.fadeout(2500) # fade out music when quitting spaceship mode
 #   else:
 # music.play(-1)   # turn on music when entering spaceship mode

        ship_mode = not ship_mode  # spaceship mode switch
        a = vector(0, 0, 0)  # reset acceleration
        sw_lbl = True  # turn on spaceship label

    # spaceship thrusters control:

    elif key == 'up':
        #a += vector(0, 0, am)  # old cartesian steering
        a += am*norm(v)  # accelerate into the direction of motion
    elif key == 'down':
        a -= am*norm(v)  # accelerate against the direction of motion
    elif key == 'left':
        a -= am*cross(norm(v),cross(norm(v),norm(s)))   # accelerate to the left of the velocity

    elif key == 'right':
        a += am*cross(norm(v),cross(norm(v),norm(s)))  # accelerate to the right of the velocity
    elif key == 'd':
        a += am*cross(norm(v),norm(s))  # accelerate to the 'top' of the velocity
    elif key == 'c':
        a -= am*cross(norm(v),norm(s))   # accelerate to the 'bottom' of the velocity
    elif key == '0':
        a = vector(0, 0, 0)  # reset acceleration

    # pre-programmed spaceship positions/scenarios:

    elif key == '1':  # Earth-Sun Lagrange point 3 (L3 - 'counter-Earth')
        s = -earthpos
        v0 = (planets[2][1][:, (int(-t + 1)) % n] - planets[2][1][:, (int(-t)) % n]) / (365.25 * 86400 / n)
        v = vector(v0[0], v0[1], v0[2])
        a = vector(0, 0, 0)
        predraw = False
        ship.trail.append(pos=s, retain=1)

    elif key == '2':  # polar orbit around the Sun
        s = vector(3e+07, -2e+06, 2e+08)
        v = vector(0, 24, 0)
        a = vector(0, 0, 0)
        predraw = False
        ship.trail.append(pos=s, retain=1)

    elif key == '3':  # orbit of the probe Helios 2  (fastest man-made object to date - 0.02% speed of light)
        s = vector(43e6, 0, 0)  # perihelion
        v = vector(0, 0, 70.22)
        a = vector(0, 0, 0)
        predraw = False
        ship.trail.append(pos=s, retain=1)

    elif key == '4':  # Halley's comet (derived using specific orbital energy, 162.3 deg inclination)
        s = vector(87813952, 0, 0)  # perihelion
        v = vector(0, 16.7, 52)
        a = vector(0, 0, 0)
        predraw = False
        ship.trail.append(pos=s, retain=1)

return ship_mode, s, v, a, dt, sw_lbl, lbl_off, predraw, ship


def mouse_check(obj, sw_lbl, lbl_off, ship_mode):
    if scene.mouse.clicked and not ship_mode:  # check if there are any 
    clicks 
in the queue

    scene.mouse.getclick()  # retrieve the click
    obj_old = obj
    obj = scene.mouse.pick  # clicked object becomes main object

    try:
        r = obj.radius
    except AttributeError:
        obj = obj_old  # if the clicked object is not a sphere (e.g. Saturn's rings), go back to old_obj
    else:
        if r > 30000000000:  # if the clicked object is a very large sphere (celestial), go back to old_obj
            obj = obj_old

    if obj != obj_old and not lbl_off:  # if different planet was clicked, switch planet label ON
        sw_lbl = True

scene.center = obj.pos  # center scene on the main object

return obj, sw_lbl`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: vpython went through a major change a couple of years ago. I think you probably got the newer one, vpython 7. This package looks to be written using the old package, vpython 6.

Comment: thx. do you know how i would uninstall the new version and install the old one

Comment: or would i have to totally rewrite the code. If so how.

Comment: You would have to mention the OS and the installation method chosen to answer that. Support for vpython 6 seems very low, see http://vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html